# CMake: What do CMake build types (DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE) do?

Tags: c++, c, cmake, clion

I am using CMake (within CLion IDE but that should not matter for this discussion). Up until now I have been using things like `set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -O2")` or `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O2")` to set compiler options for GCC. I assume CMake passes these on directly to the compiler. However, CMake is supposed to be platform independent and (at least in principle) able to build the same code using different compilers. Does this mean one should do it differently?

I have been thinking about using build configurations. For example, I assume calling CMake with a build type flag:

`cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release"`

enables some optimization. I was unable, however, to find any documentation on what exactly this flag does (maybe because it depends on things like the compiler being used). I have two questions:

1. What does -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" (and other release types) do (as exactly as one can tell not knowing the system where the build happens)?
2. What is the best way to view the compiler and **all** options actually being used at build time (both using CMake in command line and within an IDE like CLion) ?

Reading the makefile generated by CMake to find the flags does not seem like an option to me. I tried setting `VERBOSE=yes` for Make but somehow it didn't give me compiler flags, just some "entering end exiting directories".

Comment: Concerning question 2: I tried `VERBOSE=1` (rather than `=yes`) and it seems to indeed give me (all?) the commands used. To get this in CLion, I specify Settings/CMake/Build options: `-- VERBOSE=1 -j 8` (where `-j 8` refers to number of threads used for building and is the default used by CLion on my system).

Comment: `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is explained in the [cmake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html). Basically the type can select other variables based on the value of the type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. What does -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" (and other release types) do (as exactly as one can tell not knowing the system where the build happens)?

It enables certain compiler options defined in the core CMake modules, which are specific to the target system. The documentation doesn't exactly explain what each of the build types mean, but the names are fairly commonly used. I understand `Release` to mean "disable debugging, enable highest optimisation".

For example, the module `Modules/Compiler/GNU.cmake` contains following:

> ```
> string(APPEND CMAKE_${lang}_FLAGS_RELEASE_INIT " -O3 -DNDEBUG")
> ```

---

> 2. What is the best way to view the compiler and all options actually being used at build time (both using CMake in command line and within an IDE like CLion) ?

One convenient way is the compilation database. The format is specified [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html) and it is enabled with the option `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS`. The file  `compile_commands.json` will then contain the exact commands used to compile each file.

Figuring out the compiler may need additional steps if the alias `/usr/bin/c++` is used, as is common.

---

P.S. In many cases, it may be useful to enable debugging in release mode. While `RELWITHDEBINFO` does that, it doesn't enable highest optimisation (`-O2` with GCC). As such, I personally find the default choices lacking.

Answer (score 2):

It makes you switch between "Debug" and "Release" configuration. What does it mean? There are default compile flags for each language and configuration

```
CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_<CONFIG>
```

Changing from Debug to Release you are changing flags that CMake will use to set CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS.

Setting directly cmake flags "set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O2")" is not a best practice in modern cmake (version >= 3).

Why?

The modern CMake is about targets and properties. If you set flags in your project, that flags can affect other projects. (And in a huge code base it happens) So it's very important to take care of the visibility of variables and flags. Consider using [target_compile_features](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/command/target_compile_features.html), [target_compile_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html) and [target_compile_definitions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html). It makes your code more readable and less error-prone